# Properties over nested dictionary

Tags: python, properties, setter

We have properties, that work over nested dictionaries:

```
class A(object):
    _x = {}

    @property
    def z(self):
       return self._x.get('_y', {}).get('_z')

    @z.setter
    def z(self, value):
        if not self._x.get('_y'):
           self._x['_y'] = {}
        self._x['_y']['_z'] = value
```

How to create property `y` to rid off from check:

```
if not self._x.get('_y'):
   self._x['_y'] = {}
```

`z` setter must finally look like:

```
@z.setter
def z(self, value):
   self.x.y['_z'] = value
```

Comment: I don't really understand.  Maybe you are lookint for `defaultdict`s from module `collections`?

Comment: @Alfe, finally I think, I just need class with other properties, instead of dict.

Comment: Why wait until the setter is called to put `_y` in? Just initialize `_x = {'_y': {}}` and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setdefault`:

```
@z.setter
def z(self, value):        
    self._x.setdefault('_y',{})['_z'] = value
```

if `_y` exists in `self._x`, it retrieves it, else it creates a new dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, will check this way.